# DOM is not re-rendering on change of data in vue

Tags: vue.js, reactive

I am calling a method from Mounted Life cycle Hook and that method is actually calling a back end service which returns a response . But when I'm assigning that response to the Data, it is not re-rendering the DOM. I think it is not getting updated reactively. Below is my code:

```js
vmObj = new Vue({
  el: el[0],
  template: notificationTemplate,
  mixins: [translation_mixin],
  components: {
    notification_row
  },

  data: function() {
    return {
      'displayedNotification': []
    };
  },
  methods: {

    getNotificationData() {
          window.restEntity(
                        'notifications',
                        'read_notification_pref',
                        {
                            'entity': entityData, 
                            'entity_id': entityId 
                        },
                        this.onSuccess,
                        true
                    );
      //BackEnd Service which when returns a response we call "onSuccess(resp)"
    },

    onSuccess(response) {
      this.displayedNotification = response.data; //I also used this.$set but nothing happening
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.getNotificationData();
  }
});
```

Updated:

So not an answer really but i had to call the service before i am rendering the Vue(before:
`vmObj = new Vue({.....`)
instance,using `async` `await`, and saving the response in a variable and then assigning the data in the Mounted Hook, and now its working.

Comment: Please share the code in `getNotificationData`, or a codesandbox. See [mcve]

Comment: After your call to `onSuccess`, have you verified in a debugger or in Vue devtools that `displayedNotification` has the correct data you expect?

Comment: @FrankPl yes data is getting properly assigned to displayedNotification . But some how the DOM is not re rendering . there is a weird thing that i have noticed that if i put the debugger on
mounted() {
    this.getNotificationData();
  ----->>>>} on this line the re rendering is happening

Comment: @TJ getNotificationData is a default function we have that does a ajax call and the on success is a callback with the response

Answer (score 0):

You can use [nextTick](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick). It's allows you to do something after you have changed the data and VueJS has updated the DOM based on your data change, but before the browser has rendered those changed on the page.

Comment: can you please give me an example of nextTick

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `this.onSuccess` to `this.onSuccess.bind(this)`. `onSuccess` is likely losing context while called as a callback within `window.restEntity`

Comment: Actually context is not getting lost as i debugged and noticed that the data property is actually getting set but some how not re rendering and in the template i am actually running a loop on this data getNotificationData

Answer (score 0):

Presumably your assignment is losing the reactivity enhancement of `displayedNotification`. I would try to use a spread operation:

```
onSuccess(response) {
    this.displayedNotification = { ... response.data};
}
```

`$set` should have the same effect, but as you want to set the whole array, not single array elements, that would be a bit more difficult to use:

```
onSuccess(response) {
    this.displayedNotification.splice(0); // empty the array
    response.data.forEach((val, idx) => this.$set(this.displayedNotification , idx, val));
}
```